# Does Python automatically break out of a loop?

Tags: python-3.x

The code below works as expected the first time (loop, when i is 0), but when i becomes 1 the loop stops at the first `if len(k) > count:` and moves all the way down to render k empty (k is a list).

```
def longest_palindrome(string):
    if len(string) == 1 or string == "":
        return string
    k, count, output = [], 0, ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        k.append(string[i])
        if "".join(k) == "".join(k)[::-1]:
            if len(k) > count:
                count = len(k)
                output = "".join(k)
                for j in range(i+1, len(string)):
                    k.append(string[j])
                    if "".join(k) == "".join(k)[::-1]:
                        if len(k) > count:
                            count = len(k)
                            output = "".join(k)
        k = []
    return output
```

Comment: You empty `k` yourself at the last but one line.

Comment: Your code is very nested and hard to read.

Comment: Throw a print statement into the middle of the loop and you'll soon see whether values are what you expect.

Comment: For me the code is working on the input: `'12345678987654321 12321'`, which returns the palindrome `12345678987654321`. On which input isn't it working? Also to agree with the other, it might be convenient to change some expression to  their negative form, such as `if len(k) <= count: continue`, this will reduce the indentation level.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it was awfully indented.

```
def longest_palindrome(string):
    if (len(string) == 1) or (string == ""):
        return string
    k, count, output = [], 0, ""
    for i in range(len(string)):
        k.append(string[i])
        if "".join(k) == "".join(k)[::-1] and len(k) > count:
            count = len(k)
            output = "".join(k)
        for j in range(i+1, len(string)):
            k.append(string[j])
            if "".join(k) == "".join(k)[::-1] and len(k) > count:
                count = len(k)
                output = "".join(k)
        k = []
    return output
```